# subscript in axis label when using png() in base r plot

Tags: r, graph, axis-labels

I understand how to make sub/super-scripts in axis labels in base r plot. My code works fine when sending the figure straight to the R Plots section in Rstudio. However, when I try to export my graph as png, using `png()`, the `mtext()` that contains a superscript disappears.

Below is the `mtext()` code that I use- this works fine when just plotting in the R Studio screen, but it disappears when exporting to `png()`

```
mtext(side = 1, cex = 1.5,  expression ("Net Change in SO "["4"] ^"2-" *" µeq/L"), line = 3)
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this happens because you need to adjust the `line` parameter.

Start by making it 0 (default):

```
mtext(side=1, cex=1.4, "some text", line=0)
```

Comment: If this doesn't work - consider adding more details to the question. Like: what function from the base plotting are you using and what are the par parameters.